# Removing only one of many duplicate objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Say I have a list, a

```
a = [1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8]
```

I want to create a list with only duplicates of objects in a

```
dup = [4, 6]
```

Creating `dup` from `a` is easy since there is only one duplicate of 4 and 6.
So I could just simply say

```
for i in a:
    if a.count(i)>1 and i not in dup:
        dup.append(i)
```

What if `a` is like this instead

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5]
```

How do I make a `dup` list that yields

```
dup = [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Do the numbers have to be adjacent?

Comment: no. I did for clarity sake

Comment: Actually, it makes it a bit less clear. Some answers are assuming the list will be sorted ascending. I'd recommend adding an example that illustrates that this may not necessarily be the case.

Comment: no need to import any package just add one condition in `elif a.count(i)>1 and i in b: b.append(i)` and in else just continue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

cnt = Counter(a)

[k for k, v in cnt.items() for _ in range(v-1) if v>1]
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Sure--I think `.items()` could also be moved to the `cnt` as well with `list(Counter(a).items())` assuming it can be exhausted. Haven't run the code yet.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done using normal loop with `set`:

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5]
for i in set(a): a.remove(i)

print(a)   # output: [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a1 = [1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8]
a2 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5]

def f(x):
    return [i for i, j in zip(x, x[1:]) if i==j]

print(f(a1))  # -> [4, 6]
print(f(a2))  # -> [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5]
```

Comment: OP said dupes might not be adjacent.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5]
b = defaultdict(lambda: 0)

for item in a:
    b[item] += 1

desired_list = []
for value, count in b.items():
    desired_list += [value for _ in range(count-1)]

print(desired_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
for i in a:
     if a.count(i) > 1 and i not in dup:
             dup.extend([i] * (a.count(i) - 1))

>>> dup
[1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Counter or set here.

## 1 way

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5]
s = set()
result = []
for elem in a:
    if elem in s:
        result.append(elem)
    else:
        s.add(elem)
print(result)  # -> [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5]
```

## 2 way

```
from collections import Counter

a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5]

c = Counter(a)
c.subtract(set(a))
result = []
for part in ([elem] * number for elem, number in c.items() if number):
    result.extend(part)
print(result)  # -> [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do this

```
  a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5]
  dup = []
  temp_list = []
  for i in a:
      if i in temp_list:
          dup.append(i)
      else:
          temp_list.append(i)

  print (dup)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the other way of doing it!

```
def dup_val_finder(input_list):
    if isinstance(input_list,list) is True:
        data= dict()
        for i in input_list:
            if i in data.keys():
                data[i].append(i)
            else:
                dict.setdefault(data,i,[])
        dup_data = []
        for values in data.values():
            for val in values:
                dup_data.append(val)
        return dup_data
    else:
        raise TypeError("Please pass a list as the input")
        return None
```

Usage of this function is:

```
>>> dup_val_finder([1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5])
[1, 1, 3]
```

Comment: Since I don't have 50 reputation, I can't comment on @Vicrobot answer. It may make sense to copy the list before removing the items from it using b=a.copy()